# Not able to type 01 in month field first time for a texbox masked with Inputmask plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui-datepicker, masking, jquery-inputmask

I have a textbox which has a Datepicker attached to it for selecting date, along with that I have to make provision for typing in date manually from the keyboard. I have achieved that functionality using the plugin inputmask js from Github. However, when the page is first loaded and I try to enter month value as "01" for January, the masking applied to the textbox shows "10". The workaround is I can enter "11" and then change the first digit to 0, but I am looking to avoid that. I hope I am able to make you guys understand the issue Thanks in advance, I have condensed the problem into a simple code below.

P.S : I do not want the placeholder text to change as mentioned in answer below. It should be "00/00/0000" and yet allow user to type 01.

```js
var maskConfig = {
        leapday: "29-02-",
        separator: "/",
        showMaskOnHover: false,
        showMaskOnFocus: false,
        placeholder: "00/00/0000"
    }

    $('#datepicker1').inputmask('mm/dd/yyyy', maskConfig);
    
    $('#datepicker1').datepicker({
        dateFormat: "mm/dd/yy",
        changeMonth: true,
        changeYear: true,
        
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.inputmask/3.3.4/jquery.inputmask.bundle.min.js"></script>

<input type="text" id="datepicker1"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

Change this line

```
placeholder: "00/00/0000"
```

to:

```
placeholder: "01/00/0000"
```

```js
var maskConfig = {
        leapday: "29-02-",
        separator: "/",
        showMaskOnHover: true,
        showMaskOnFocus: true,
        placeholder: "01/00/0000"
    }

    $('#datepicker1').inputmask('mm/dd/yyyy', maskConfig);
    
    $('#datepicker1').datepicker({
        dateFormat: "mm/dd/yy",
        changeMonth: false,
        changeYear: false,
        
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.inputmask/3.3.4/jquery.inputmask.bundle.min.js"></script>

<input type="text" id="datepicker1"/>
```